# @MockBean of service returns real instance instead of mock in @WebMvcTest(s)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, controller, mockito

so I was doing tests under `@WebMvcTest`, and I just noticed that the mocking using `@MockBean` of my service, that my controller uses, is not working. I honestly don't know what to do. I'm using Spring Boot 3.1.2. Also, some things are in spanish. It goes like this:

```java
@RestController
public class ClienteController implements IClienteController {

    private final ClienteService clienteService;
    private final CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry;

    @Autowired
    public ClienteController(ClienteService clienteService, CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry) {
        this.clienteService = clienteService;
        this.circuitBreakerRegistry = circuitBreakerRegistry;
    }

    @CircuitBreaker(name = "clienteCircuitBreaker", fallbackMethod = "fallbackCircuitBreaker")
    @Retry(name="clienteRetry")
    @RateLimiter(name="clienteRateLimiter", fallbackMethod = "fallbackRateLimiter")
    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public ClienteModel getCliente(@RequestParam int tipoDocumento, @RequestParam long nroDocumento) {
        return clienteService.getCliente(tipoDocumento, nroDocumento);
    }
}
```

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ClienteController.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Import({CircuitBreakerConfiguration.class,
    RetryConfiguration.class,
    RateLimiterConfiguration.class,
    SecurityConfig.class})
public class ClienteControllerTests {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean
    ClienteService clienteService;
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private ClienteModel crearClienteModelValido() {...}

    @Test
    public void pasaRequestCorrecta() throws Exception {
        //dado
        when(clienteService.getCliente(anyInt(), anyInt())).thenReturn(crearClienteModelValido());

        //entonces
        String response = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/clientes")
                .param("tipoDocumento", "0")
                .param("nroDocumento", "10000000")
                .with(httpBasic("admin", "password"))
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn()
            .getResponse()
            .getContentAsString();

        ClienteModel cliente = objectMapper.readValue(response, ClienteModel.class);
        //...
    }
}
```

It all started when I checked that the Body in `MockHttpServletResponse` was simply empty, when it should have an object. Then, debugging, I noticed that the `clienteService` in the tests and in the controller was a real instance instead of a mock (as far as I can tell): `clienteService = {ClienteService@8607}`. That means that the `when(...).thenReturn(...)` is doing nothing, which explains the empty response later.

So I don't know what to do, I've checked various posts related to this but none solve my problem. Thinking about it, though, I remember something when I first started testing the app. I was doing `@SpringBootTest`(s) only, so I used `@Autowired` and `@MockBean` exclusively. In that occasion, I remember having trouble with `@Autowired`, as it seems it wasn't able to autowire things correctly. I remember solving it by adding explicitly `JUnit 4` to the pom.xml, for some reason. I recently removed it because I was redoing the tests from scratch and it seemed unnecessary, but maybe it has something to do with it?

Note: `CircuitBreakerRegistry` is also a real instance (look at the controller). That doesn't surprise me though because I'm not mocking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting the mock injected; otherwise, this line
`when(clienteService.getCliente(anyInt(), anyInt())).thenReturn(crearClienteModelValido());` would throw an exception.

I suspect you aren't seeing the desired behavior because your matchers don't match the argument types.

Your matchers indicate that you're calling this method with `(int, int)`, but you're calling it with `(int, long)`.

Change your mock stubbing to reflect the argument types that you're passing and you should be good.

```
when(clienteService.getCliente(anyInt(), anyLong())).thenReturn(crearClienteModelValido());
```

Comment: You're right, and it worked! Weird, because I remember noticing that and changing it right after posting the question, and having no effect. I think I only checked the type of `clienteService` when debugging instead of just running the test, that's why. 
So, of note, `clienteService = {ClienteService@8607}` was a mock after all. Like you said, if it werent, the code would have broken in `when(...).thenReturn(..)`.